# How to prevent email scripts to be considered as spamming by servers

Tags: php, email

I have just coded an simple email script.but just right a day after I got an email saying from my server admin that you have uploaded a script which is sending email so remove it as it will do spamming..! so I need suggestions what should I do or why it is considered as spamming script..cuz I am not doing any type of spamming through this script..?

Here is that email please :

```
Note: If this is the first time you received this mail, it contains the history for the entire month so far.

Below are the recently upload scripts that contain code to send email. You may wish to inspect them to ensure they are not sending out SPAM.

/home/webngrap/public_html/mail/mail.php:22: 
/home/webngrap/public_html/mail/mail.php:23: $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
/home/webngrap/public_html/mail/mail.php:24: 
 ---
Thanks
```

Also here is the Email script please :

```
$to = "nicefellow1234@gmail.com";
$header = "FROM: Jack Sparrow <some@site.com>\r\n";
$subject = "Test";
$message = "It's Just A Test";

$sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if ($sendmail) {
echo "Email Send Successfully";
} else {
echo "Email Sending Failed";
}
```

Waiting for your replies..!

Comment: You might want to post your script.

Comment: Sure..let me post the script..!

Comment: This is an automated email, it doesn't mean your script is sending SPAM its simply a warning to you to inspect as it may have been uploaded by another user or by some one attempting to exploit your server.  Your script is fine as you don't allow an end user to modify any of the to/from/subject/body fields.

Comment: It is a system generated warning. It doesn't mean that it is sending spam, just that it has the ability to email.

Comment: @cmorrissey looks like you bet me to the trigger...

Comment: Thanks...for your answers...as the server admin is asking me to delete the script..! so should I tell him that this is not sending spam or what should I do?

Comment: Just keep in mind, if you use a form in any way to create the variable strings, you need to validate the user input so that they don't put malicious code in there.

Comment: @John : Sure...good idea...validation is always best to prevent bad things..!

Comment: You should use a service like mailgun[free up to 10k emails per month], this allows you to appear more reputable than a random server/ip address sending messages

Comment: @Brian Putt : Thanks..for your suggestion..!